# BigQuery - Cannot use count distinct with scoped aggregation

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table as

```
+--------+------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+ 
|visit_id|browsed_categories            | num_seen| num_borrows |
+--------+------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|1       |  fiction,history             | 20      | 3           |
|2       |  selfhelp,fiction,science    | 15      | 3           |
|3       |  cooking,kids,home,selfhelp  | 7       | 2           |
+--------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

and am attempting to summarize this table to find if a correlation exists between the number of distinct browsed categories and borrowals.

```
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| borrow_rate | num_distinct_browsed_categories | distinct_categories     | 
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  0          | 3                               | cooking,selfhelp,home   |
|  1          | 2                               | history,fiction         |
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

My query is as follows:

```
select
  *,
  count(distinct(split(all_cats, ','))) as num_distinct_browsed_categories
from
(
  select 
    (num_borrows/num_seen) as borrow_rate,
    count(visit_id) as num_visits,
    group_concat(browsed_categories, ',') as all_cats
  from [table]
  group by borrow_rate
)
```

The query gives me this error:

```
Cannot use count distinct with scoped aggregation
```

How should I modify the query to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is version for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cat) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(all_cats, ',')) cat) AS num_distinct_browsed_categories  
FROM (
  SELECT 
    (num_borrows/num_seen) AS borrow_rate,
    COUNT(visit_id) AS num_visits,
    STRING_AGG(browsed_categories, ',') AS all_cats
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY borrow_rate
)
```

Btw, if for some reason you still bound to BigQuery Legacy SQL - just replace

```
count(distinct(split(all_cats, ',')))
```

with

```
exact_count_distinct(split(all_cats, ','))
```

in your original query

Comment: Thanks! Using exact_count_distinct() function worked.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the "all_cats" column contains any value from a given list of values?